# can't change date on debian stable (virtualbox)

Tags: linux, debian, virtual-machines, virtualbox, debian-lenny

At first i tried to change date to good one via gnome via 'Time and Date Settings' but when i clicked on calendar i couldn't change date. So i tried via console... `date +%T -s "02:36:00"` worked fine and time is set to it now... but `date +%m%d -s "1019"` returned old date instead of the one i'm trying to set... what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happier with a format that's closer to the ISO standard year-month-day:
eg. date -s "2009-10-19 13:30:00"

That would set it to 19th October 2009 at 1:30pm.

Comment: I've noticed that if I run this command in modern systems (Ubuntu 20.04, Fedora 32) putting a past date (like this date -s "2010-12-23 15:00") , inmediately "something" overwrites the time in order to restore it to the current time again. Do you know what thing is doing this? Thanks!

Comment: Well, I've discovered it: because I have the NTP client service enabled (systemd-timedated).

Answer (score 0):

The format string only controls the output. You need to at least specify a time in your date.

```
date "10192125"
```

and optionally a year

```
date "101921252009"
```

To set only a time:

```
date -s "2125"
```